# How to prevent child component from re-rendering when using React hooks and memo?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I just started experimenting with React hooks and I'm wondering how I can prevent a child component from re-rendering when it's parent re-renders.  I'm looking for something similar to returning false in `componentDidUpdate`.  My issue seems to stem from the click handler I'm calling in the child component to change state in the parent component.  Since the function is created in the parent component, it is created new on each parent render which triggers a prop change in the child component, which then causes the child to re-render **(I think)**.  Here is some sample code to help illustrate the situation.

```
function Parent() {
    const [item, setItem] = useState({ name: "item", value: 0 });

    const handleChangeItem = () => {
        const newValue = item.value + 1;
        setItem({ ...item, value: newValue });
    };

    return <Child item={item} changeItem={handleChangeItem} />;
}

const Child = React.memo(function Child({ item, changeItem }) {
    function handleClick(){
        changeItem();
    }
    return (
        <div>
            Name: {item.name} Value: {item.value}
            <button onClick={handleClick}>change state in parent</button>
        </div>
    );
});
```

How do I prevent Child component from rendering every time Parent component renders?  Should `handleChangeItem` in the parent live someplace else so that it is not re-created on each render?  If so, how does it get access to `item` and `setItem` returned by `useState`?

I'm pretty new to react and just started playing with hooks so I'm probably missing something obvious.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

In your case it doesn't really makes sense to memoize Child because if item changes, the child has to re-render. However if there is a case that props do not change , but still the child is re-rendering due to the functions getting recreated you would make use of [`useCallback`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#are-hooks-slow-because-of-creating-functions-in-render) hook to memoize the functions, on each render. Also since you have memoized the handler, you should make use of the callback method to update state since `item` inside the handler will only refer to the value it had when the function was initially created

```
function Parent() {
  const [item, setItem] = useState({ name: "item", value: 0 });

  const handleChangeItem = useCallback(() => {
    setItem(prevItem => ({ ...prevItem, value: prevItem.value + 1 }));
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      Name: {item.name} Value: {item.value}
      <Child changeItem={handleChangeItem} />
    </>
  );
}

const Child = React.memo(function Child({ item, changeItem }) {
  function handleClick() {
    changeItem();
  }
  console.log("child render");
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>change state in parent</button>
    </div>
  );
});
```

[Working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/ovpm81zj36)

**P.S.** [Credit to @danAbramov for the direction](https://twitter.com/dan_abramov/status/1081016340582944768)

Comment: This answers the question although I ended up using `useReducer` with `dispatch` passed via context (`useContext`).  This is the preferred approach and is clearly described in the hooks docs/faq.

Comment: This is the perfect answer, Awesome!!

Comment: this approach causes performance fallback otherwise using `memo` would be default in all hooks, which makes me thinks how you solve this problem when you dumped the simple solution like `componentDidUpdate` to adapt hooks.

Comment: @Jalal There is a similar API  to `memo` called as `PureComponent` for classes which can be used to prevent unncessary rerendering but needs to be used judicously according to your use case since the expense for props comparison may overweigh the expense of re-rendering. Also useCallback is a way to memoize functions to avoid closure problems which is why react in the first place provides it. It should be used when the state and state updaters are not complex else you can go ahead with using `useReducer`

Comment: Agreed, but still using  classes in this case more powerful than hooks. I cal easily use `shouldComponentUpdate ` to have full control over the component which is missing in hooks.

Comment: @Jalal You can use `memo` and implement the same logic with functional component too. and ofCourse there are lots of things that are debatable but as far as my experience goes with Hooks, it has a steep learning curve but is extremely cool once you get along with it and all your related logic is at one place

Comment: what's an alternative of `useCallBack` for class component. I have a situation where parent component is class and child component is function, and child is updating parent's prop which causes child to re-render and that's what I want to avoid.

Answer (score 5):

Shubham Khatri accurately answered the original question but I am adding this answer to point to the recommended way of avoiding this callback problem.

From the docs:

> > useReducer is usually preferable to useState when you have complex
> >     state logic that involves multiple sub-values. It also lets you
> >     optimize performance for components that trigger deep updates because
> >     you can pass dispatch down instead of callbacks.
>
> https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer

From the FAQ:

> > In large component trees, an alternative we recommend is to pass down
> >     a dispatch function from useReducer via context...
>
> https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-to-avoid-passing-callbacks-down

The key to all of this is that dispatch never changes, unlike callbacks which are created every render.