# Custom hook cause poor performance, although optimizing with useCallback will not reflect the new state

Tags: reactjs, performance, react-hooks

I am doing some React Hooks experiment and encountered a pretty bombing problem.

I am trying to create a custom form state hook.
I created a **very very simplified version** of my work just to demonstrate the problem here: https://repl.it/@kadoshms/useCallbackCapture

The code itself is here (To keep it simple I kept all the code in the same main file):

```
import React, { Component, useState, useCallback } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

const myHook = (e) => {
  const [values, setValues] = useState({
    checked: []
  });

  const setFormValues = useCallback((e) => {
    // some logic 
    if (e.currentTarget.checked) {
      setValues({
        checked: [...values.checked, e.currentTarget.value] 
      });
    } else {
      setValues({
        checked: values.checked.filter(v => v !== e.currentTarget.value)
      });
    }
  }, []);

  return [values, setFormValues];
}

const checkboxes = Array.from({length: 222}, (v, k) => k+1); 

const Checkbox = (props) => (
  <input type="checkbox"
      name={props.name}
      value={props.value} 
      checked={props.checked} onChange={props.onChange} />
);

// Checkbox.whyDidYouRender = true;

const Form = () => {
  //
  const [formData, setFormData] = myHook();
  return (
    <form>
      {checkboxes.map((c) => <Checkbox name="foo" checked={formData['checked'].includes(c.toString())}
       key={`c-${c}`} 
      onChange={setFormData} value={c} />)}
    </form>
  );
  //
};

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Form />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

The problem is pretty much self explanatory in the example I provided.
The **useCallback** hook probably captures the last state which causes the `checked` array not to update.
Adding the `formData` as a dependency, or on the other hand remove  the memoization will fix it. 
Altough, that might cause a performance problem since the **onChange** handler is closured in every render.

My goal is to use hooks but keep great performance, hence every checkbox should update only if it's **checked** value is changed.

**Edit:** I can fix the issue using a custom React.memo callback, similar to shouldComponentUpdate, though I think it's less elegant.

Is that possible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible Duplicate of [Prevent Child components re-rendering due to use of hooks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54015086/how-to-prevent-child-component-from-re-rendering-when-using-react-hooks-and-memo/54034325#54034325)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some further reading, I encountered the following FAQ section in the official React docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#are-hooks-slow-because-of-creating-functions-in-render

**TL:DR:** Instead of using `useState` I created a reducer using `useReducer` hook, like specified in the docs.
If someone is interested, I'll be glad to share my solution for the specific problem above.