# How to remove the renderer of a functional memoized component that contains a child component in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

When writing a handler for several different inputs, I ran into the problem of re-rendering components in which there are child components. How can I remove the renderer?

Only components **without** children and components using **useMemo** are not rendered.

This is only part of the code.
Here [full code](https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-mendeleev-6yf5c).

```
// handle changes from input
export const useInputHandler = ({ initValues }) => {
  const [values, setValues] = useState(initValues || {});

  const handlerChange = useCallback(
    event => {
      const target = event.target;
      const name = target.name;
      const value = target.value;

      setValues({
        ...values,
        [name]: value
      });
    },
    [values]
  );

  return [values, handlerChange];
};
```

```
const App = () => {
  const [clicksNum, setClicks] = useState(0);

  const countClicks = useCallback(() => {
    setClicks(c => c + 1);
  }, []);

  const [values, handleChange] = useInputHandler({
    initValues: { simple: "", counter: "", empty: "" }
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("VALUES: ", values);
  }, [values, clicksNum]);

  return (
    <div style={{ display: "flex", flexDirection: "column", width: "30%" }}>
      <Button onClick={countClicks} />

      <Input onChange={handleChange} name="simple" value={values.simple}>
        {<div>hello</div>}
      </Input>

      <Input onChange={handleChange} name="counter" value={values.counter}>
        {clicksNum}
      </Input>

      <Input onChange={handleChange} name="empty" value={values.empty} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

I expect that the input components will not be re-render every time the button is clicked. In this case, only the second input (which name **counter**) should be redrawn. Because it wraps up the value (**clicksNum**) of the state.

Comment: This is actually interesting, once you remove the `{<div>Hello</div>}` only 2nd input will rerender.

Comment: @keysl, yes it is. But what if this component is needed? For example, I will need to send there not a `{<div>Hello</div>}`, but a `<Button />`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54015086/how-to-prevent-child-component-from-re-rendering-when-using-react-hooks-and-memo is this help for you

Comment: @JanakaDissanayake this is not exactly what I need. :)
Your example shows how to pass props from a child component to a parent component without unnecessary redraws. But in my case, it is necessary that the parent component does not redraw children who do not change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your input re-renders, because it's children change.

`{<div>Hello</div>}` is a different instance at every render.

If you replace this with something like this:

```
const hello = useMemo(() => <div>Hello</div>, []);
```

It will only create a new instance if any of the dependencies change. There are no dependencies, and your re-renders will be gone.

You can always prevent unwanted re-renders by memoizing any of your components, it will then re-render only if any of the dependencies change.

```
const memoizedInput = React.useMemo(
  () => (
    <Input onChange={handleChange} name="simple" value={values.simple}>
      <Button onClick={countClicks} />
    </Input>
  ),
  [handleChange, countClicks, values.simple]
);
```

Comment: Yes I understand this. But what if, instead of `<div>Hello</div>`, you put a component created using memo function? For example, if you put my `<Button /> ` component there. This also does not work. Although the child component is memoized. What to do in this case? This is the main question. :)
Here а slightly modified [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/wrong-re-render-memoized-m69pv).

Comment: You can memoize your input component, no? How about something like this: https://codesandbox.io/embed/wrong-re-render-memoized-lvti9

Comment: it works as it should. But is this approach really right? And why need to wrap it up if the `<Input />` is already memoized? The props passed to `<Input />` do not change when the button is pressed.

Comment: Please note, that React.memo and React.useMemo are two different methods. You can not optimize components that use React.children props with React.memo, React.memo does not memoize children props. If you do really want to optimize on that level, you can meoize a function call that creates children and it fixes the issue.

Comment: Thank you, I didn’t know that at each renderer the child element has different props. Indeed, if we compare the _prevProps_ and _nextProps_, we can see that `prevProps.children._owner` not equal `nextProps.children._owner`. Therefore, a re-render occurs, despite the fact that the component is memoize.

Comment: You can also return a value calculated by React.useMemo from your Input component and add prop dependencies. So you won't have to memoize every input  like that.