# How to not re render the parent of a child component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I’m having re-rendering issues, any help is greatly appreciated. I tried useMemo and useCallback and it broke the checkbox. I have a component, and inside that component, I display some info in my object. I have let's say an object as such:

```
fakeObject = {
name: "rectangle"
width: 10
height: 20
visible: true
}

const fakeComponent = () => {
const [checked, setChecked] = React.useState(true);

  const handleChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setChecked(event.target.checked);
    fakeObject["visible"] = event.target.checked;
  };
return(
   <div>
   <h2> {fakeObject.name} </h2>
   <p> The height is {fakeObject.height} </p>
   <Checkbox
      checked={checked}
      onChange={handleChange}
      inputProps={{ 'aria-label': 'controlled' }}
    />
  </div>
)
};
```

The issue is that every time I click my checkbox it rerenders the whole component. This is a simplified version of my issue but I see that the component uses my fakeObject and that the checkbox changes that but how do I make it so that my whole component doesn't re-render? Thanks for any help

Comment: Every time your state changes, component re-renders and all the components that use that state get re-rendered too. That's what react does.

Comment: you cannot because `checked` is a state of `fakeComponent` and therefor it triggers the re rendering

Comment: seems like a duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54015086/how-to-prevent-child-component-from-re-rendering-when-using-react-hooks-and-memo

Comment: @ymz mine is slightly the opposite? like not re render the parent rather than not re render the child

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to not re render the parent of a child component?

It's possible, but you would have to move all the logic responsible for checking the checkbox to the child component (`Child`).

```
const Checkbox = () => {
  const [checked, setChecked] = useState(false);
  console.log('child re-render');

  return (
    <input
      value={checked}
      type="checkbox"
      onChange={() => setChecked((prev) => !prev)}
    />
  );
};
```

Then, you don't even need to worry about `memo`.

Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/modest-star-y0z3xt?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Thanks this did help in some scenario

Answer (score 0):

The parent component will be re rendered because you are saving the checked state on the parent component with a useStateHook, if you would like to avoid re render a component you can use [memo](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo) but you need to remove the hook where you want to avoid re render.